# url rewriting while url creates dynamically

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

> I had rewrite a URL from example.com/service.php?p_id=1&s_id=seo to example.com/1/seo/. 
>   By The following rule:

this rule is for example.com/services.php?p_id=1&s_id=seo

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /services\.php\?p_id=([^&\s]+)&s_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ services.php?p_id=$1&s_id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Now the problem is that when i use the following rule for another url like example.com/about-us.php?p_id=1&s_id=2 and for example.com/it-training.php?p_id=1&s_id=2 then the url redirects as example.com/1/2/index.php but it should be as example.com/1/2 ,

formated rule for about-us.php is given bellow

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /about-us\.php\?p_id=([^&\s]+)&s_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ about-us.php?p_id=$1&s_id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

In other case i have some url like example.com/packages.php, index.php, i also want to remove the .php from that kind of files

Comment: Are you sure these are the only rules as first rule cannot impact `/about-us.php` OR `/it-training.php` since it matches `/services\.php` in the URL.

Comment: see the updated question again...is it possible in that case...

Comment: ok this is indeed the problem. `example.com/1/2` cannot handle both `/about-us.php` and `/services.php`. You should use `example.com/about/1/2` and `example.com/services/1/2` for both.

Comment: Sir actually in example.com/1/2   1=about-us and 2=vision in data base, my main objective to rewrite the url in the form of example.com/about/vision   instead of    example.com/1/2           example.com/service/seo   instead of    example.com/1/2  ,

Comment: I will wait for your opinion about that problem.....

Comment: I actually don't know what to tell you. You need to build little more understanding of pretty URL rewriting. Take for example how StackOverflow is doing it where they include both question_id and question-title in the URL.

Comment: ok....but simply how can i use the code given by you for other urls like about-us.php ....and for some more urls....how is it possible that the rule is only working for service.php but not working for about-us.php? i want to rewrite same as for about-us.php.....give ur opinion

Comment: That I have already told you to keep pretty URLs as `example.com/about/1/2` and `example.com/services/1/2` etc.